# JS Replace text in between unique expression in parentheses (i)

Tags: javascript, regex

My intention is to build a parsing function which searches within a string (think blog post) for any substrings wrapped around unique identifiers in parentheses, like (i).

My current implementation isnt working. Would truly appreciate any help!

```
let text = "Hello there (i)Sir(i)";
let italics = /\(i\)(.?*)\(i\)/gi;
let italicsText = text.match(italics);
// text.replace(italics, <i>)
```

Comment: what is the input and what exactly output do you want. Please add sufficient information.

Comment: @NullPointerException my bad, added a string with an example. The intention is to replace (i)Sir(i) with <i>Sir<i>

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: `let italics = /\(i\)(.*?)\(i\)/g; let italicsText = text.replace(italics, "<i>$1</i>");`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Good Lord, was the issue just with the order of (.*?)  ??! Thank you so much man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) here with regex as:

```
\((.*?)\)/g
```

Second argument to [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is a replacer function.

```
replace(regexp, replacerFunction)
```

> A function to be invoked to create the new substring to be used to
> replace the matches to the given regexp or substr.

[`How arguments are passed to replacer function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

```js
let text = 'Hello there (i)Sir(i)';
let italics = text.replace(/\((.*?)\)/g, (_, match) => `<${match}>`);
console.log(italics);

let text2 = 'Hello there (test)Sir(test)';
let italics2 = text2.replace(/\((.*?)\)/g, (_, match) => `<${match}>`);
console.log(italics2);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I am perplexed by the second half of the replace function, however. Could you possibly explain it to me? Or how I could modify this to search specifically for certain characters?

Comment: Just change the regexp to be the characters you want to replace . For example, `'(a)(b)(c)(d)(e)(i)'.replace(/\(([aei])\)/g, (_, match) => \`<${match}>\`);`

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript "replaceAll" function:

```js
let text = "Hello there (i)Sir(i)";
console.log(text.replaceAll("(i)", "<i>"));
```

Comment: This is not right solution to this problem. It will work if we have to replace `(i)` with `<i>` only.  What if the input is `(test)Sir(test)`

Comment: @NullPointerException The OP is not asking to replace everything in parentheses with brackets. It seems to be some kind of markdown.